# Is there any email marketing service which send emails to gmail primary tab?

Tags: email

I am using Mailchimp as my email marketing service. But almost all emails delivered to "promotion tab".

Is there any email service which are sent to primary tab?

Comment: No, Google is considering your email promotional due to the content within, so using a different provider will not change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented with both marketing and transactional mail and like mentioned below content and headers play a reasonable part in it. Obviously keeping compliant is important so you have restrictions of your own and your mail providers.

Have a read of the quotes below and the article source at the bottom, maybe you can get a happy medium:

> **Achieving Delivery to the Primary Inbox**
>
> So how can you help ensure that your email makes it to a recipient’s
>   primary inbox? While there’s no secret sauce, I did play around a bit
>   and found some helpful insights.
>
> When I first tested SendGrid’s transactional messages, they were all
>   going to the Promotions folder. So, I tested a number of different
>   configurations on my account and also moved my account to different IP
>   groups. What did I find?
>
> - Open and click tracking: Open and click tracking didn’t affect which tab the message was delivered to, and neither did the IP.
> - Subscription tracking: I was able to get delivery to the Primary tab from SendGrid by disabling the Subscription tracking.
>     (Subscription tracking is implemented through SendGrid’s Subscription
>     Tracking App which automatically inserts an unsubscribe link and an
>     X-List-Unsubscribe header.) I manually added an unsubscribe link to
>     the message and delivery to the Primary tab was maintained.
> - Content: To test content, I took some content from a marketing message I received and sent it through SendGrid without a
>     list-unsubscribe header; this resulted in the message being delivered
>     to the Promotions tab. Because of this, I believe that both the
>     list-unsubscribe header added by subscription tracking and content are
>     used by Gmail to determine which tab to deliver the message to. The
>     message also had a tracking image used by a third party email
>     marketing service, meaning that domains could also be used, however
>     after several tests I wasn’t clear if domains were used to determine
>     tab placement.
>
> But not to fear, recipients can still be in control of their inbox by
>   overriding Gmail’s default settings.

**Key Takeaways**

> - Content plays a part: test your messages prior to using new content
> - Your headers matter: the unsubscribe header affects which tab your message is delivered to
> - Ask for recipient involvement: You can send out a re-confirmation email asking recipients to add you to their Primary tab to help ensure
>     delivery
> - Web and mobile are affected: Be sure to optimize and test your emails for both users
> - The inbox is still adapting: Some messages may be misclassified in Gmail’s new inbox. Google’s system learns and adapts as users
>     reclassify their mail, so Google’s classification accuracy will
>     improve over time.

Because Gmail learns (from customer use) which emails recipients do or don’t want and adjusts accordingly, this places even more importance on sending wanted and valuable email. We will continue to monitor these email stats and let you know what new information we find. But in the meantime, check out our additional best practices posts that will help you ensure that you’re sending quality email.

Source : https://sendgrid.com/blog/the-new-gmail-tab-layout-oh-yeah-or-uh-oh/

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Build/Choose_Content/gmail_promotions_tab.html

Note,  I use Sendgrid as a transactional and marketing platform, hence giving their take on it.